# Next.js 13 - Change Server Action Content-Type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm calling a server function on a client component, by looking at the request when the server function runs, the request content-type is *text/plain;charset=utf-8*.

It´s possible to change the request to *application/json;charset=utf-8* ?

Comment: Could you add the code you're using, just so we can see how you're using this? Thanks.